# How do I make this bitwise code more concise?

Tags: bash, shell, bit-manipulation

My bitwise code which works is:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

random=$((RANDOM % 32));

bitWiseAnd() {
    local IFS='&'
    printf "%s\n" "$(( $* ))"
}

echo "random=${random}";

if [ $(bitWiseAnd ${random} "0x10") -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "1"
else
    echo "0"
fi

if [ $(bitWiseAnd ${random} "0x8") -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "1"
else
    echo "0"
fi

if [ $(bitWiseAnd ${random} "0x4") -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "1"
else
    echo "0"
fi

if [ $(bitWiseAnd ${random} "0x2") -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "1"
else
    echo "0"
fi

if [ $(bitWiseAnd ${random} "0x1") -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "1"
else
    echo "0"
fi
```

A sample output from the above code:

```
random=15
0
1
1
1
1
```

I have no idea how this code works. Can this code be made more concise?

Comment: How is it "your" code if you don't know how it works?

Comment: @Inian Ah yes. It's just a continuation of the OP's last question that was closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `for` loop instead of repeated `if` blocks.  Also, the `for` loop spells out your purpose more clearly, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

bitWiseAnd() {
  local IFS='&'
  printf "%s\n" "$(( $* ))"
}

random=$((RANDOM % 32));
echo "random=${random}";
for i in 10 8 4 2 1; do
  if [ $(bitWiseAnd ${random} "0x$i") -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "1"
  else
    echo "0"
  fi
done
```

Output:

```
random=10
0
1
0
1
0
```

---

Also, the function below

```
bitWiseAnd() {
    local IFS='&'
    printf "%s\n" "$(( $* ))"
}
```

could be made more explicit this way, as long as we are looking at just two input arguments:

```
bitWiseAnd() {
  printf "%s\n" $(($1 & $2))
}
```

Comment: Note that `IFS` is not changed permanently, just within the scope of the function, it is just a local variable there.

Comment: @danday74, do you think this is a good exercise in compacting your code?  If so, you could accept my answer.

Comment: @Inian - thanks for the related post.  I liked your answer there.

Answer (score 1):

This *won't* produce the exact same output as you need, because you asked for an optimization and it doesn't involve multiple useless `echo` statements.

Another approach would be using a while-loop and check if bit-positions are still valid. I have removed the useless `echo` statements, assuming you don't need any of that and *just* want to improve the code.

```
bitMask="0x10"
while [ $(bitWiseAnd "31" "$bitMask") -ne 0 ] && ((bitMask))
do
    bitMask=$((bitMask >> 1))
done
```

Just replace the hard-coded number `31` with the variable value `$random` and `bitMask` of your choice.

Comment: It won't produce the same output as in OP's code, isn't it?

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain what idea was it caused you to do it?